# Running MSTest UnitTests using a MSBuild Script

Tags: .net, msbuild, mstest, msbuild-task, vs-unit-testing-framework

Could you please guide me how to run MSTest unit tests using an MSBuild script.

Comment: These two sites, both found with a quick google search may help you out. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/cb87a184-6589-454b-bf1c-2e82771fc3aa

Comment: I've posted an answer on another thread with a MSBuild script that is able to run the vstest.console.exe (it replaces MSTest). You can view it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21743192/3304079

Answer (score -2):

you should use default configuration for running any assemblies including your unit test and this assembly usually ended with test.dll 
good luck