# Using VSTest to run unit test cases instead of MSTest

Tags: c#, xaml, tfs, visual-studio-2012, build-process

I have an x64 platform C# solution(VS2012) on a TFS2010 server. I have attached a unit test project (also x64)  to this solution and created a build definition. When I queue the build, it succeeds but the unit test cases will not be executed. This is because MSTest is a 32 bit application. So, I decided to customize the default build process template (DefaultTemplate.xaml) to invoke VSTest(VSTest.console.exe) instead of MSTest. This is quite complex and I am unable to add a build activity to the toolbox for VSTest.

Has anyone done this kind of customization? I have also considered other approaches like configuring .runsettings file. Do we have a  VSTest adapter interface that can be added in the .runsettings file ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Executing unit tests through VSTest and publishing the test results through MSTest gave me a successful outcome. Given below is the Powershell script:

```
#  Get the UnitTest Binaries
$files = Get-ChildItem $TestAssembliesDir\*est*.dll

#  VSTest.console.exe path
$VSTestPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe'

#  MSTest path
$MSTestpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"
#  Loop through the test assemblies and add them to the VSTestFiles

$VSTestFiles = ''  
foreach($file in $files)  
{   
    $VSTestFiles += "`"$file`"" 
    $VSTestFiles += " "
} 

#  Run the UnitTests using VSTest 
&$VSTestPath  $vstestplatform "/Framework:Framework45" "/InIsolation" $VSTestFiles "/logger:trx"

#  Get TRX files
$TrxFilesList = Get-ChildItem $TestResDir\*.trx
$TrxFiles = ''  
$loop = 1
foreach($file in $TrxFilesList)  
{   
    $TrxFiles = "$file" 
    # copy the trx file into a space-less named trx
    $newTrxFileName = "$BuildUri" + "_" + "$loop" + ".trx"

    copy-item $TrxFiles -destination $TestResDir\$newTrxFileName

    $loop = $loop + 1
    $newTrxFile += "$TestResDir\$newTrxFileName"
    $newTrxFile += " "
} 

#  specify MSTest arguments 
$mspubl = "/publish:"+$TeamProjColUri
$msteampr = "/teamproject:" + $TeamProj
$mspublbuild = "/publishbuild:" +$BuildUri
$mspubresfile = "/publishresultsfile:" +"`"$newTrxFile`""
#Publish test results through MSTest
&$MSTestpath  $mstestplatform $flavor $mspubl $msteampr $mspublbuild $mspubresfile
```

Comment: Great. Especially the part for finding the generated trx file. Thank you.

Comment: Why is `$MSTestpath` declared and never used? Where is `$TestResDir` declared and what is it set to?

Answer (score 4):

I too have the exact same need for using VSTest.Console.exe instead of MSTest.exe for a TFS2010 build process that compiles a VS2012/.NET 4.5 x64 application, while waiting for the upgrade to TFS2012 to commence.

The approach I have taken was to edit the build script XAML, deleted the existing workflow for unit tests and replaced it with a customised workflow that builds up the VSTest.Console.exe parameters and then executes VSTest.Console.exe via InvokeProcess. I then ensured that in the Finally block that regardless of test result that we publish the test results and code coverage to TFS using MSTest.exe from a VS2012 installation on the build server.

Unfortunately I cannot post the XAML in the answer as it exceeds character length, but I do have a text file consisting of the snippet to be replaced in DefaultTemplate.xaml and what to replace it with. The file can be found [here](http://users.tpg.com.au/kostat//BuildScriptSnippet.txt). Please note that although this approach works it is a hack.

Another alternative would be to use NUnit instead of MSTest or VSTest.Console as this support 64-bit binaries. This [article](http://blog.ianbattersby.com/2012/01/04/tfsbuild-2010-nunit-integration/) explains how to integrate NUnit in a TFS2010 build script, and has links to tools and resources required to make this happen. The only issues with NUnit are code coverage (need yet another tool plus work out how to publish these results to TFS) and MSTest-style integration tests using attributes such as DeploymentItem and properties such as TestContext, which is why where I work we opted with the VSTest.Console.exe approach.

And from what I have read TFS2012 offers easy integration to VSTest.Console.exe from build scripts, so if you do ever upgrade to TFS2012 the VSTest.Console.exe hack that I have documented may not be required.

Comment: I have discovered that there is an issue with specifying test categories, especially when you want to set up test execution to ignore tests belonging to a particular test category. I overcame this by adding a new argument to the build XAML called TestCaseFilter, and setting VSTest.Console.exe's TestCaseFilter parameter if the build definition's TestCaseFilter argument has been specified. In the build definition under Misc, you can then set the TestCaseFilter to whatever it is that you require, in my case "TestCategory!=IntegrationTest"

Comment: Thanks a lot Kosta :) I was able to do the vstest execution part for the unit test cases through a powershell script. But Im facing some problems in publishing the results. Ill go through your solution for that. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello @Arkanoid, you may not necessarily need to throw out your PowerShell script, as from what I'm gathering it would be doing the same thing as what I have done straight in XAML. As long as in your PowerShell script you get VSTest.Console.exe to generate a TRX file you can then call MSTest.exe to publish that TRX file to TFS, and that the call to MSTest.exe is made regardless of whether VSTest.Console.exe was successful.

Comment: @KostaTenedios Thank for sharing this -- it is a GREAT solution.  For anyone else implementing this, make sure to note that both the Team Project and TFS server URI are hard coded; you can replace them with variables.  Also, you will need to import in the 'st' namespace into your Build Definition.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer you question, but it might help. I did a similar thing for TeamCity. I used command-line to call vstest.console.exe and created a .runsettings file.

I used this [Microsoft template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) for the runsettings file. Note however that on my machine, the path mentioned in the comment in Line 5 is relative to the .runsettings location, not the .sln.

If you use /logger:trx option of vstest.console.exe, it will generate output in the same format as MSTest (good for result visualization).