# Unble to rename Test results (.trx) generated from VSTest.console.exe

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, vstest

I am trying to set name and file location for my Test results (.trx) generated from VSTest.Console.exe from console line but looks like its not working.

If I run below command,
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "MyTest.dll" /UseVsixExtensions:"true" /InIsolation **/Logger:"trx"**

It copies test results in below default location,

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\TestResults{user-name}{machine-name}{datetime}.trx

In order to avoid this default location and name for test results, when I specify output path in logger it gives below error:

**Error: Could not find a test logger with URI or FriendlyName 'C:\UnitTest\MyResults.trx'.**

Below is the command I am using,

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "MyTest.dll" /UseVsixExtensions:"true" /InIsolation /**Logger:"C:\UnitTest\MyResults.trx"**

Let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by "works" and "does not"

Comment: "works" means it generates a report but in a root directory but does not give me an option of selecting a directory. "does not" in this case the command doesnt work when i try to specify a output report path.

Comment: what do you mean "command doesn't work". you need to be very clear. that could be interepretted as "the command fails to run" or "the command runs with unexpected results".

Comment: Updated my question, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483837/specifying-results-filename-for-vstest-console-exe